# Store TMDB API data

Tags: json, swift, api, decode

I'm working on an app that requires the use of the TMDB API. I have been trying to store the results from the API in a struct but it keeps giving me the error:

> No exact matches in call to subscript

This is the struct:

```
struct MovieList: Codable {
    let dates: Date?
    let page: Int?
    let results: [Result]?
    let total_pages: Int?
    let total_results: Int?
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let adult: Bool?
    let backdrop_path: String?
    let genre_ids: [Int]?
    let id: Int?
    let original_language: String?
    let original_title: String?
    let overview: String?
    let popularity: Int?
    let poster_path: String?
    let release_date: String?
    let title: String?
    let video: Bool?
    let vote_average: Float?
    let vote_count: Int?
```

And here is my API call:

```
public class LoadTMDBData {

  var tmdbMoviesData = [[Result]]()

init() {
  getTMDBData()
}

func getTMDBData() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "") else {
          fatalError("Invalid URL")
      }
    // Set session configuration to default
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      
      // Check that data has been returned
      guard let data = data else { return }
      do {
        let tmdbData = try JSONDecoder().decode([MovieList].self, from: data)
        self.tmdbMoviesData = tmdbData["result"]
      }
      catch{
        let error = error
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
  // execute the HTTP request
  task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Never post your api key online, I have edited it out but you should probably get a new one. A comment on your code is that in the error handling for the decoding you shouldn't use `localizedDescription` but instead do `print(error)` since this gives you a much more detailed error message. Lastly, if possible always point out which line generates the error unless it is obvious

Comment: When you don't even show how the original JSON data look, it'll be difficult for others to find your mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a struct you don't access its properties using a string key like ["someProperty"], instead you use dot notation .someProperty, so to get the `results` property you do

```
let results = myMoveList.results
```

What makes it a little more complicated here is that you have, as you properly have coded for, an array of MovieList and that you want to extract all results into an array for array.

For this you can use a high order function `map` to do this

```
self.tmdbMoviesData = tmdbData.map(\.results)
```

but since `results` is optional we use a similar function that will filter out any nil values, `compactMap`

```
self.tmdbMoviesData = tmdbData.compactMap(\.results)
```

Another comment, you have made all properties optional in your structs and while this is an easy way forward it might lead to hiding some decoding issues and more cumbersome code when using the types. I would recommend not to use optional unless really needed.

Comment: Thank you yes I will do. I just wanted to ask im trying to access the title value in my view controller using: let cell = UITableViewCell()
      let movies = data[indexPath.row]
      let title = movies["title"] as! String
      cell.textLabel?.text = title               but it keeps giving me a no exact match to call in subscript. Can you help with this, please?

Comment: It’s the exact same mistake I wrote about in the answer in the 1st paragraph